# Get count on two columns Using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the count on two columns using the sample data below.

Sample data

```
Project       Node
------------------
Project1      Node1
Project2      Node1
Project3      Node2
```

Sample output

```
3 Projects 2 Nodes
```

Comment: Please explain the logic behind your result.

Comment: How it come 2 projects specify logic..

Comment: Sorry it should be 3 projects. The logic behind that is simple to count the project and node using a simple query without using CTE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't normally post an answer without trying to extract some evidence of effort but....

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Project), COUNT(DISTINCT Node) FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Any other approach other than distinct?

Comment: There are a couple of other approaches posted here. I think they're all inferior to DISTINCT though. Why do you ask? exam question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select sum(Project) as project,sum(node) as node from(
select count(Project) as Project,0 as node from tablename 
Union all
select 0 as Project,count(node) as node from tablename)a
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT Project) as varchar(50))+' Projects '
     + CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT Node) as varchar(50))+ ' Nodes'
FROM dbo.YourTable
```

Comment: Any other approach other than distinct?

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    count(project) as project, 
    count(distinct node) as node 
from test;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27b2b1/9)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you don't want to use `distinct` as you have commented on other answers, but this will work without `distinct`.  It's uglier, though - usually not a good idea unless you need to do a `partition` or some other syntax that doesn't allow `distinct`.

```
select max(DR_Nodes) as Nodes, max(DR_Projects) as Projects
from
(
  select *
  , dense_rank() over (order by node) as DR_Nodes
  , dense_rank() over (order by project) as DR_Projects
  from test
) a
```

or, even uglier:

```
select * from
(select count(*) as Nodes from
    (select node
    from test
    group by node) a
) a
inner join
(select count(*) as Projects from
    (select project
    from test
    group by project) b
) b
on 1 = 1
```

Comment: Yeah right, I though that group by is better than Distinct. Since they are the same according to Google, I will stick in Distinct.